# jquery imgareaselect and facebox

Tags: php, jquery, img-area-select-jquery

I am trying to integrate imgareaselect (http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop-v11/) and facebox (http://defunkt.io/facebox/) however I am having no luck at all and hoping someone can help.

imgareaselect calls a

```
 header("location:");
```

command after the image is uploaded but this actually reloads the entire page not just the facebox component. I am quite stuck with this as I have never used the imgareaselect plugin before.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you could try replacing `header("location:");` with:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.facebox({ image: \'newCroppedImage.jpg\' });</script>';
```

below are some different facebox methods as shown on http://defunkt.io/facebox/

```
 **Arbitrary Text**
    jQuery.facebox('something cool');
    jQuery.facebox('something cool', 'my-groovy-style');
    **Remote files**
    jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'remote.html' });
    jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'remote.html' }, 'my-groovy-style');
    **Image**
    jQuery.facebox({ image: 'images/stairs.jpg' });
    jQuery.facebox({ image: 'images/stairs.jpg' }, 'my-groovy-style');
    **A Page Element**
    jQuery.facebox({ div: '#box' });
    jQuery.facebox({ div: '#box' }, 'my-groovy-style');
```